# I cannot get a list of players on Android Studio via MySQL, PHP, Volley in descending order of points

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am attempting to display a list of players ranked by number of points, number of photos and their highest score on Android Studio with RecyclerView. What happens is I get a list of the same username, points, photos and highscore at the size of the total number of usernames

I want my Android screen to present something like this...
[MySQL table (via XAMPP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOYH9.png)

Here is my PHP code - It seems fine to me, as I've tested it by writing the localhost name

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, points, photos, highscore FROM users ORDER BY points DESC, photos ASC, highscore DESC;");

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($username, $points, $photos, $highscore);

$players = array();

while($stmt->fetch()){
    
    $temp = array();
    
    $temp['username'] = $username;
    $temp['points'] = $points;
    $temp['photos'] = $photos;
    $temp['highscore'] = $highscore;
        
    array_push($players, $temp);
    
}

$stmt->close();

echo json_encode($players);

?>
```

[PHP test via localhost address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5fAK.png)

When it comes to trying to display it on Android, [I get the following output...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpFkB.png)

Here is my code for the Android:

rankings.java

```
public class rankings extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private List<player_object> players;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rankings);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    manager = new GridLayoutManager(rankings.this, 1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    players = new ArrayList<>();

    getPlayers();
}

private void getPlayers(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLs.URL_RANKING,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0 ; i<array.length() ; i++){
                            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            String player = object.getString("username");
                            int points = object.getInt("points");
                            int photos = object.getInt("photos");
                            int highscore = object.getInt("highscore");

                            player_object gamer = new player_object(player, points, photos, highscore);
                            players.add(gamer);
                        }
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(rankings.this, players);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

            Toast.makeText(rankings.this, "internet gone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(rankings.this).add(stringRequest);
}
```

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<player_object> players;

public RecyclerAdapter (Context context, List<player_object> players){
    this.context = context;
    this.players = players;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_rankings_row,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    player_object player = players.get(position);

    holder.rank.setText(Integer.toString(position+1));
    holder.gamer.setText(player.getPlayer());
    holder.points.setText(Integer.toString(player.getPoints()));
    holder.photos.setText(Integer.toString(player.getPhotos()));
    holder.highscore.setText(Integer.toString(player.getHighscore()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return players.size();
}

/*public*/ class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    /*private*/ TextView rank;
    /*private*/ TextView gamer;
    /*private*/ TextView points;
    /*private*/ TextView photos;
    /*private*/ TextView highscore;
    /*private*/ LinearLayout container;

    public MyViewHolder (View view){
        super(view);

        rank = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_rank);
        gamer = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_player);
        points = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_points);
        photos = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_photos);
        highscore = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_highscore);
        container = view.findViewById(R.id.player_container);
    }
}
```

player_object.java

```
public class player_object {

private static String gamer;
private static int points;
private static int photos;
private static int highscore;

public player_object(String gamer, int points, int photos, int highscore) {
    this.gamer = gamer;
    this.points = points;
    this.photos = photos;
    this.highscore = highscore;
}

public String getPlayer(){
    return gamer;
}

public int getPoints(){
    return points;
}

public int getPhotos(){
    return photos;
}

public int getHighscore(){
    return highscore;
}

public void setPlayer(String gamer){
    this.gamer = gamer;
}

public void setPoints(int points){
    this.points = points;
}

public void setPhotos(int photos){
    this.photos = photos;
}

public void setHighscore(int highscore){
    this.highscore = highscore;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `player_object`, remove `static` from each of the class variables.  They will take the last value that is set as they are not tied to the objects you have created.